# Is there a verb that means "the act of replacing a word or phrase with an ellipsis"?

Tags: single-word-requests, ellipses

Is there a verb that means "the act of replacing a word or phrase with an ellipsis"?

"*Ellipsize*" doesn't seem to be in the dictionaries. Is there a word for this?

Comment: I often find 'ellipt' useful (because ellipses occur so frequently) ( http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ellipt ). I wouldn't use the description _'replacing' a word ..._, logical though it might appear.

Comment: Normally it's called "deletion", if the idea is that it was there and taken out, or "omission" if the idea is that it was never there. Depends on what kind of "replacing" you think takes place, and how it works. Here's a [list of English syntactic rules](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Preliminarybufattenedlistoftransformations.pdf), including deletion rules.

Comment: The long-winded explanation was ellipted from the published text.  I like it.  Even if it isn't common, it should be understood.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Exactly what I'm looking for! Write that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 9):

I would use the word "elide", meaning to omit.  It's usually used for spoken language (as in "midwestern US speakers frequently elide the 'g' in gerunds like 'running'), but can be used for written language as well.

Comment: Think again, using an ellipsis (...) is not the same as elision.

Comment: From http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elide : " a : to suppress or alter (as a vowel or syllable) by elision
b : to strike out (as a written word)
2
a : to leave out of consideration : omit
b : curtail, abridge "  Thus "elide" has both the meaning of "omit" and "merge"; it is perhaps not the absolute perfect 100% no question about it word to use, but I think that of all the English words, it is probably the *best* one to use here.

Comment: (I would be delighted to learn an even better word.)

Comment: A minor quibble, but in most American pronunciations there is no *g* on the end of words such as *running*; what is happening is the velar nasal is replaced by the alveolar nasal. No elision of any sound, but rather substitution.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a common word, but **ellipt** has this meaning:

> to delete by ellipsis ([RH](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ellipt))

[Oxford Reference](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780192800879.001.0001/acref-9780192800879-e-454) gives this definition and usage:

> Omit (an element) by ellipsis. 1990 S. GREENBAUM & R. QUIRK In MEDIAL ellipsis medial elements are ellipted: Jill owns ...

Comment: Did you notice this was proposed in the first comment?

Comment: @PhilSweet Yes.  I'm not sure why it wasn't put into an answer three years ago, but it's the answer that I was looking for when I stumbled on this question.